# How to set a variable from the bash $PS1

Tags: bash, variable-assignment, ps1

The bash `PS1` variable seemingly has access to all the shell's variables.

```
$ foo=bar
$ PS1='$foo '
bar # Works as expected.
```

But, setting a variable there does not work.

```
$ PS1='$(bar=baz)\$ '
$ echo $bar

$ # Does not work.
```

**Why**, and **how to make this work?**

Comment: The shell IS the process that is interpreting the contents of `PS1` before displaying the prompt so `$$` will only ever refer to the shell process.

Comment: @D.Shawley If I put a script such as `$(show-me-the-PID.sh)` in the `PS1`, the `PID` will change each time. I said that because this behavior was unexpected to me as a novice.

Comment: In that case, the evaluation of `PS1` is creating a subprocess and running _show-me-the-PID.sh_ in the new child process.

Comment: @D.Shawley Yeah, and this is unexpected to me because scripting languages in general don't do this, but I see that it may be silly to note this fact, I'll edit it.

Comment: Terminology note: You are talking about _shell_ variables, not _environment_ variables. All environment variables are also represented as shell variables, but the converse is not true. `bar` in your code is a mere _shell_ variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why:

The `PS1` variable is evaluated as a string. In a bash string, you can do this:

```
$ myString="$foo"
```

And this:

```
$ myString="Date: $(date)"
```

But not this:

```
$ myString="$(foo=bar)"
```

The `PS1` variable is simply not exempt from this rule.

**Note:** as [mkelement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) explains in the comments, this is because the `foo=bar` part will be executed in a subshell, so you could do `$(foo=bar;echo $foo)`, though - it's just that the variable will only exist in that scope.

## How to make this work:

There's another variable, called `PROMPT_COMMAND`. The code here will be `eval()`'d at each prompt string, before the evaluation of the `PS1` variable.

Thus, even just writing your assignment here as-is will work:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='bar=baz'
$ echo $bar
baz # Works!
```

Remember to check if you're not overwriting previously-set contents in the `PROMPT_COMMAND` that you may want to keep, though.

Comment: Helpful in general, but 'prepending it to the PS1 variable` is confusing: Perhaps you meant that _output_ - if any - from `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is printed before the primary prompt is displayed. As for why `$(foo=bar)` doesn't work the way you want: `$(...)` is called command substitution and it runs the enclosed command in a _subshell_, which is a child process that receives a _copy_ of the current shell environment, without being able to change the _current_ shell's environment. Note, however, that the variable assignment _is_ effective _inside_ the subshell.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, edited the answer with your input.